# I want to display only single toast when proximity sensor is covered

Tags: android

I want to display only single toast when proximity sensor is covered.When using the below code toast is continuously displaying.
here is my code.....

```
class sense extends Activity implements SensorEventListener
{
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mSensor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
    }

protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
    if (event.values[0] == 0)
    {
            Toast.makeText(sense.this,"near", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy)
{
}
}
```

Comment: Add a flag to show it one time

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a flag like a timestamp that will be set to the current time when the toast is shown. When you are about to show a toast the second time you check to make sure that the current time - the last time is passed a certain threshold (5 minutes or whatever you choose) If it has been more than the threshold then show the toast. If not, then don't show the toast.

Answer (score 0):

set Flag to Toast Single time

```
    boolean flag = false;
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(event.sensor.getType() == sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY){
        if(event.values[0] == 0){
          flag=true;
          if(flag == true){
         Toast.makeText(sense.this,"near", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         } 
        }
    }
```